# UIBarButtonItem not responding to click

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a UITableView where I want the user to be able to click two buttons, in the header of the section, one for adding a new record, and the other one for editing them, so I first tried using `tableView viewForHeaderInSection` and `tableView heightForHeaderInSection` like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 44;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     UIView* v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 360, 44)];
    UIToolbar* tb = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 44)];

    UIBarButtonItem* spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem* addBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(onAddVehicleInterest:)];
    UIBarButtonItem* editBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(onEditVehiclesInterest:)];

    [tb setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, addBtn, editBtn, nil]];

    [v addSubview:tb];
    return v;
}

- (IBAction)onAddVehicleInterest: (id) sender {
    NSLog(@"Add");
}

- (IBAction)onEditVehiclesInterest:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Edit");
}
```

When I run the app, I can see the three UIBarButtonItems correctly, and I can click them, but the NSLog line is never called.  So I added a `UIToolbar` directly in the nib file, added the 3 `UIBarButtonItem` controls to it, and tied the `onAddVehicleInterest`and `onEditVehiclesInterest` to the respective buttons.  But that doesn't work either...

So, as a last test, I added a `UIButton` to the nib and tied its Touch Up Inside event to one of the methods, and that works as expected.  So I'm confused.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just tested your code and it runs fine for me.

Comment: Thanks @Ander, your test gave me an idea and I was right.  I have a gestureRecognizer on the parent view and that was messing with the event of the buttons.  Once I added a test for that (Checking if the superview is UIToolbar), it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

I had a UITapGestureRecognizer on the parent view of the view controller. Once I removed the tap gesture, my UIBarButtonItems began to respond properly to all selectors.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same problem  and I get it solved by changing:-

```
- (IBAction)onAddVehicleInterest: (id) sender {
to 
- (IBAction)onAddVehicleInterest: (UIBarButtonItem *) sender {
```

I also dont know why it was not working earlier, but my problem solved with it.
You can try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIBarButtonItem* addBtn;
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(onAddVehicleInterest:)])
{
    addBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(onAddVehicleInterest:)];
}

UIBarButtonItem* editBtn
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(onEditVehiclesInterest:)])
{
    editBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(onEditVehiclesInterest:)];
}

if(addBtn && editBtn)
{
   [tb setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, addBtn, editBtn, nil]];
}
```